# How to find which delegation tasks an Active Directory group has

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been handed a task to find which delegation task a specific Active Directory group has been given, and I am having hard time with it.

Please help

Comment: You mean someone used the "Delegation Wizard" in Active Directory Users and Computers console to grant permissions to specific groups, and you want to "reverse engineer" these assignments?

Comment: Yes Mathias this is what I need

Comment: Have you tried this one? https://www.easy365manager.com/how-to-document-ou-delegation/

Answer (score 0):

You may use dsacls Microsoft tool to list AD permissions on an OU or container:
For example:
Dsacls OU=Employee,DC=Contoso,DC=Com

This will give you a report on which user/Group has rights on this OU / Container in a readable format.

You can use ADSI Edit or dsquery Microsoft tools to find DN of an object/OU/Container. Then you should input the DN attribute to the dsacls command line utility.

If you can not find dsacls download at microsoft.com, there are very similar tools at github.com